# Docker container interact mode auto closing issue in docker-machine

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I have installed Docker using Docker toolbox in my Windows 7. I have installed Cassandra container. I am able to interact with container by ( `docker exec -it <CON_ID> /bin/bash`. after entering few commands in container , i am kicking out of the container.But, container is still running. example I am giving simple PWD, ls commands.

How to extend interact time in container ?

Docker toolbox version: 1.12.2

I didn't create any docker file for container. I have followed below steps,

1. docker run --name=mycass -d -it -p 9042:9042  cassandra:2.1.11
2. docker exec -it mycass /bin/bash

I am able to interact with container . after simple 2 commands ( pwd, ls ) getting kicked out from container.

Comment: Can you add steps to reproduce the issue, please ?

Comment: please share the `dockerfile`

Comment: I have updated details. please check and help me

Comment: any help on my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I have executed ( **docker-machine ssh default** ) command and it opened Boot2Docker after that I am bale to connect container with interactive mode ( **docker exec -it  /bin/bash/** without any session close. But I don't the technical reason behind this.

```
       ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.11.0, build HEAD : 32ee7e9 - Wed Apr 13 20:06:49 UTC 2016
Docker version 1.11.0, build 4dc5990
docker@default:~$
```